# How to recalculate a field in another model based on the calculations of one model in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

There are three models in my project, that are:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    diagnosis=models.ForeignKey(Diagnosis, on_delete=CASCADE)
    treatment=models.ForeignKey(Treatment, on_delete=CASCADE)
    patient_type=models.ForeignKey(PatientType, on_delete=CASCADE)
    date_of_admission=models.DateField(default=None)
    max_fractions=models.IntegerField(default=None)
    total_package=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

class Receivables(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    pattern = RegexValidator(r'(RT|rt|rT|Rt)\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}', 'Enter RT Number properly!')
    rt_number=models.CharField(max_length=15, validators=[pattern])
    discount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    approved_package=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    proposed_fractions=models.IntegerField()
    done_fractions=models.IntegerField()
    base_value=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    expected_value=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True)

    @property
    def package(self):
        try:
            return Package.objects.filter(patient=self.patient).order_by('-id').first()
        except Package.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def calculate_approved_discount(self):
        if(self.package):
            if self.package.patient_type=='CASH':
                self.approved_package = self.package.total_package - self.discount
        else:
            pass

    def calculate_base_value(self):
        if (self.package):
            process_charge=self.package.total_package*15/100
            net_total_package=self.package.total_package - process_charge
            amount_per_fraction=net_total_package/self.package.max_fractions
            net_cost=amount_per_fraction*self.done_fractions
            gross_cost=net_cost+process_charge
            self.base_value=gross_cost
        else:
            self.base_value=self.approved_package

    def calculate_expected_value(self): #Edited
    if not self.expected_value < 0:
        if (self.package):
            if self.base_value<self.approved_package:
                self.expected_value=self.base_value
            else:
                self.expected_value=self.approved_package
        else:
            self.expected_value=0
    else:
        return abs(self.expected_value)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.calculate_approved_discount()
        self.calculate_base_value()
        self.calculate_expected_value()
        super(Receivables, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Realization(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    cash=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    amount_received=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    billing_month=models.DateField(default=None)
    deficit_or_surplus_amount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    deficit_percentage=models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0)
    surplus_percentage=models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0)
    remarks=models.TextField(max_length=500, default="N/A")

    @property
    def receivables(self):
        try:
            return Receivables.objects.filter(patient=self.patient).order_by('-id').first()
        except Receivables.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    @property
    def discharge(self):
        try:
            return Discharge.objects.filter(patient=self.patient).order_by('-id').first()
        except Discharge.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    @property
    def package(self):
        try:
            return Package.objects.filter(patient=self.patient).order_by('-id').first()
        except Package.DoesNotExist:
            return None


    def calculate_deficit_surplus_amount(self):
        if (self.receivables):
            print(self.receivables)
            self.deficit_or_surplus_amount=self.amount_received-self.receivables.expected_value
        else:
            self.deficit_or_surplus_amount=0

    def calculate_deficit_or_surplus_percentage(self):
        if (self.receivables):
            if self.amount_received>self.receivables.expected_value:
                self.surplus_percentage=self.deficit_or_surplus_amount/self.receivables.expected_value*100
                self.deficit_percentage=0
            elif self.amount_received<self.receivables.expected_value:
                self.deficit_percentage=self.deficit_or_surplus_amount/self.receivables.expected_value*100
                self.surplus_percentage=0
            elif self.amount_received==self.receivables.expected_value:
                self.deficit_percentage=0
                self.surplus_percentage=0
        else:
            self.surplus_percentage=0
            self.deficit_percentage=0

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.calculate_deficit_surplus_amount()
        self.calculate_deficit_or_surplus_percentage()
        super(Realization, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**EDIT:**

Now what I want is when a patient is paying the amount and if there is deficit (which is contained by deficit_or_surplus_amount), I want that deficit amount to be saved in the expected_value of Receivables, so that when we reclaim the amount, the further calculations would be based on that expected_value, when we do receive the deficit amount.

I don't want to delete the previous instances but rather create a new instance of Receivables that has a new expected_value which now carries what was paid less the last time. So we expect that amount from the patient. So when the patient pays the next time, the deficit or surplus would be calculated on the basis of what was expected of him to pay this time.

For example:

If a patient gets admitted and has a Government scheme pay for him. Suppose the total expected_value is 75000 from him. He gets discharged and the we claim the amount to the Government. When we receive the amount, we get less amount, let's say we received only 70000. So 5000 deficit. We reclaim the repudiated amount. Now we expect to receive 5000 from the Government, not 75000. So if we receive the amount from the scheme and it is not 5000, instead it's only 2500, so the Realization table's methods should be able to calculate the deficits or surpluses based on the now expected_value, i.e, 5000.

I hope my question is clear now. If you still want further explanation , please let me know.

I tried to use a signal for this purpose:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Realization)
def new_receivable_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    pkg=Package.objects.filter(patient=instance.patient).order_by('-id').first()
    rec=Receivables.objects.filter(patient=instance.patient).order_by('-id').first()
    if created:
        if pkg.patient_type!='CASH':
            if instance.deficit_or_surplus_amount<0:
                Receivables(
                    patient=rec.patient, 
                    rt_number=rec.rt_number, 
                    discount=rec.discount, 
                    approved_package=rec.approved_package, 
                    proposed_fractions=rec.proposed_fractions, 
                    done_fractions=rec.done_fractions, 
                    base_value=rec.base_value, 
                    expected_value=abs(instance.deficit_or_surplus_amount)
                ).save()
```

This function does create a new instance of `Receivables` but with the previous `expected_value` and not the recalculated one.

Where am I going wrong? How should I go about that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try add super() in first line.
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
      super(Receivables, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
      self.calculate_deficit_surplus_amount() or whatever line you wanna add

Comment: @mehedi Sorry, didn't get you. Can you please elaborate? I'd really appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Receivables, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            self.calculate_approved_discount()
            self.calculate_base_value()
            self.calculate_expected_value()
            self.save()

Comment: you can try this code if thats help you

Comment: But it's already there. And I believe that Receivables won't be able to access Realization's attributes and methods as Realization is created after Receivables. Am I missing something?

Comment: @LordElrond Yes, I'm totally allowed to change it. But until now, it all was working just fine. Do you have any changes in mind that might smooth it up a bit? I'm practically new to Django and finding it a little overwhelming with such an issue. I have been able to tweak and correct the codes most of the times, but here, I can't find a way out. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @LordElrond I'm making this app for a company operating in oncology related services. We provide radiotherapy to cancer patients. The radiations are given in fractions. Each patient gets a fixed number of fractions for a fixed price. That is max_fractions for the total package. However, based on the requirement, the doctors may propose less fractions to be given to the particular patient and out of those proposed fractions, the patient may end up getting even lesser fractions of radiation for some reasons, death and quick recovery are one of those reasons.

Comment: @LordElrond So this fluctuates the amount to be received. And I'm using Postgresql. Do let me know if you need anything more, I'd love to hear what you have in your mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving the `deficit` amount correctly every time.

But you are not saving/updating the `expected_value` at all.

The first time you are saving the `expected_value` from `base_value` which is correct.

The next time amount received you have to update the `expected_value` (It has to be 5000, 2500).

- 75000 `base_value`, 75000 `expected_value`.
- 70000 `amount_received` - 5000 `deficit`   - 5000 `expected_value`.
- 2500 `amount_received` - 2500 `deficit` - 2500 `expected_value`.
- 1300 `amount_received` - 1200 `deficit` - 1200 `expected_value`.

Here you are doing `amount_received` - previous `expected_value` (70000 - 75000 = -5000). You are doing in a negative/reverse way. Thats fine.

But `Receivables` model has `save()` which contains `calculate_expected_value`

```
    def calculate_expected_value(self):
        if (self.package):
            if self.base_value<self.approved_package:
                self.expected_value=self.base_value
            else:
                self.expected_value=self.approved_package
        else:
            self.expected_value=0
```

This method is overriding the `expected_value` in this model. It is not taking the passing expected value while initializing the `Receivables(....).save()` object.

Try modify above method like this:

```
def calculate_expected_value(self):
    if not self.expected_value < 0: # try something here, if expected value exists already while saving, we don't reassign it below.        
        if (self.package):
            if self.base_value<self.approved_package:
                self.expected_value=self.base_value
            else:
                self.expected_value=self.approved_package
        else:
            self.expected_value=0
```

This is where you might be going wrong. Please correct me if I am wrong.

EDIT:

```
def calculate_expected_value(self): #Edited
    if not self.expected_value < 0:
        if (self.package):
            if self.base_value<self.approved_package:
                self.expected_value=self.base_value
            else:
                self.expected_value=self.approved_package
        else:
            self.expected_value=0
    else:
        exp_value = self.expected_value * -1
        return exp_value
```

Comment: So do you suggest that I make another method in Realization like def recalculate_expected_value and make it change as per the amount received? And this way I wouldn't have to use signals?

Comment: No. You can simply edit the method calculate_expected_value() and take the expected_value in it, the signal is right. Edited the answer.

Comment: Okay, good suggestion, let me work on it and I will get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: That did work partially. It now captures the updated expected_value but a negative amount. The negative figure is alright in deficit_or_surplus_amount is good but it should be converted to a positive number after being shifted to expected_value. Please look at the updated expected_value method in my post. I have tried to convert the figure to a positive number by enclosing it into abs() method but to no avail. Any suggestion about that?

Comment: So far I know, abs() method will be useful for float. You can simply multiply by -1 if negative. Modified the answer.

Comment: What's happening is the save() method in the model isn't saving the data finally, it's the save() method in the signal that's finally saving the instance and that instance has the negative value. If I change the value of deficit_or_surplus_amount there, then calculate_expected_value wouldn't work the way I want it to as its whole dependability to execute the modified data is the <0 condition. So, that's where it's getting complicated.

Comment: As far as the abs() method is concerned, I tried to print the value using it and it did print the positive number perfectly. The calculate_expected_value(), upon being called, also returns the positive number with abs(). But I think this method has no say in saving the final data.

Comment: Even multiplying the value by -1 doesn't help. I tried.

Comment: Oh! ok. In that case, you can save it positively. But while accessing the data (while doing operations using expected_value multiply by -1 wherever needed). is amount_received positive value?

Comment: Cool, let me try.

Comment: That is working! Thanks. I'm accepting your answer. Just have one question, if any doubt regarding this issue arises, may I send you a chat request? It's perfectly fine if your answer is no. :)

Comment: Yes, you can send me chat request.

Comment: Thanks a ton! :)